# REST service: select an appropriate method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

What is the logic of selecting an appropriate web-service method in the case of the next code?

client:

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("admin", "admin");
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
final Response response = client.target(webServiceURI).request().get();
System.out.println(response.getMediaType());
```

service:

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello World RESTful Jersey!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</title>" + "<body><h1>" + "Hello World RESTful Jersey"
                + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

Why response media type will be `text/html` ? What is the rule which defines it? What if I need `text/xml` in response for example?

Comment: `.request(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get()` or `request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get()`

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it is the accept header in the request that defines which format the response should be in. For more information, see the following link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

I hope that the answer helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your container will probably use the Accept header in the request to determine which of the three methods to call. If request only includes text/plain in the Accept header, it will call the one that returns text/plain, etc. More info in the content-negotiation docs here: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.0.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html